# How to configure Azure App Service application settings for ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

This ASP.NET Core 3.1 application works fine on the local machine, but when hosted in Azure App Service it does not use the configuration variables set under "Application settings".

The following variables have been created inside of the App Service configuration with the same values set in `appsettings.json`:

- SearchServiceName
- SearchServiceQueryApiKey

How can the controller file method below be changed to use the `appsettings.json` file locally, and the Azure App service configuration settings in the cloud? `appsettings.json` is not being included in the repository in Azure DevOps that is built and deployed to Azure App Service.

#### Controller file method:

private void InitSearch()

```
{
    // Create a configuration using the appsettings file.
    _builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    _configuration = _builder.Build();

    // Pull the values from the appsettings.json file.
    string searchServiceName = _configuration["SearchServiceName"];
    string queryApiKey = _configuration["SearchServiceQueryApiKey"];

    // Create a service and index client.
    _serviceClient = new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, new SearchCredentials(queryApiKey));
    _indexClient = _serviceClient.Indexes.GetClient("example-index");
}
```

#### appsettings.json

```
{
  "SearchServiceName": "example-search-service",
  "SearchServiceQueryApiKey": "example-query-api-key",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: `appsettings.json is not being included in the repository in Azure DevOps that is built and deployed to Azure App Service` sounds strange - how are you publishing the `appsetting.json` if it is not stored in the source control repository ? You can have appsettings.json for several environments and load the config according to environment `var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json").AddEnvironmentVariables();`

Comment: appsettings.json is not being pushed to the repository because it contains sensitive information. It is being ignored by Git.

Comment: You can use `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` when `ConfigurationBuilder` is used to built config. And move all your sensitive information to the [Azure app service environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#environment-variables-configuration-provider). For example environment variable with name `Logging:LogLevel:Default` and value `Warning` will override the `Logging\LogLevel\Default` value in the `appsettings.json`. Logins and passwords can be stored in the Azure app service environment variables like this.

Comment: `How can the controller file method below be changed to use the appsettings.json file locally and in the cloud` The code you have shown looks fine. Do you have any error when reading configuration like this locally (or in the cloud)? Do you have `appsettings.json` file in the same folder as the main assembly? I've built app that is executed locally and in the cloud and it uses the same `ConfigurationBuilder` sequence as your sample. The only one difference is `.SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)` used in my case.

Comment: "environment" does not exist in the controller.

Comment: `IHostingEnvironment environment` is the `Startup.Configure` method parameter. like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked. "IWebHostEnvironment" must be brought into the controller class using a dependency injection pattern.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    public MyController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        this._environment = env;
    }

    private void InitSearch(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // Create a configuration using the appsettings file.
        _builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        _configuration = _builder.Build();

        // Pull the values from the appsettings.json file.
        string searchServiceName = _configuration["SearchServiceName"];
        string queryApiKey = _configuration["SearchServiceQueryApiKey"];

        // Create a service and index client.
        _serviceClient = new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, new SearchCredentials(queryApiKey));
        _indexClient = _serviceClient.Indexes.GetClient("example-index");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The configuration settings set in an Azure App Service are provided to the app itself using environment variables. With that in mind, you can just add the environment-variable provider to your `ConfigurationBuilder`, like this:

```
_builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

See [Override app configuration using the Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#override-app-configuration-using-the-azure-portal) for more information.